# How to Find History Tracking or Audit Log field in Custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, history-tracking, field-history

I have a custom object and I have enabled the checkbox [Tract Field History](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=0&language=en_US) my question is, how can you show your tracking field histroy in Visualforce Page?

I need a way to show the customer what has been changed `Username`, `DateTime` etc...

I just need a way to know what is involved in order to display this data.

Comment: Why do you think you need a `Visualforce Page`? You can just use the OOB `Related List` in your `Page Layout`.

Comment: what is OOB ? well... I haven't done this before so I'm not sure, what approach to take.

Comment: Out Of Box. It comes pre-built. Are you just trying to add them to the `Page Layout`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `Visualforce` at all to display them in the `Page Layout`. You can look at the `Related Lists` for your object, search `Hist...` and you should see something like `Account History`.

If you're trying to add it to an existing `Visualforce Page` instead of a `Page Layout`, simply use the **[`<apex:relatedList>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm)** tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:relatedList list="Histories" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: As I'm exploring the more options, I'm looking at the apex:component and in order to use the component I can not use standardController, in this case how would you use apex:relatedList list= Histories? any guidance?

Comment: @NickKahn Honestly, that's kind of a different question, and you might want to provide a bit more detail when you ask it.

Answer (score 1):

@Nick Kahn,
If you intend to use an `apex:component`, then you might have to query `AccountHistory` object that you could use in the component.

AccountHistory Query example:

```
SELECT AccountId, Account.Name, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate, Field, OldValue, NewValue 
FROM AccountHistory
```

Comment: Why downvote any explanation?